# Read/Write binary files overflow

Tags: vb.net

I am wanting some help with some code please. Here is my code:

```
    Public Function ReadBinaryFileLarge(strFilename As String) As Byte()
    Dim position As Integer = 0
    Dim bufferSize As Integer = 4096
    Dim bytes() As Byte

    Using fsOpen As FileStream = New FileStream(strFilename, FileMode.Open)
        ReDim bytes((fsOpen.Length) - 1)
        Do
            If (position + bufferSize) > fsOpen.Length Then
                fsOpen.Read(bytes, position, fsOpen.Length - position)
                Exit Do
            Else
                fsOpen.Read(bytes, position, bufferSize)
            End If

            position += bufferSize

            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
    End Using

    Return bytes

End Function

Public Sub SaveBinaryFileLarge(strFilename As String, bytesToWrite() As Byte)
    Dim position As Integer = 0

    Using fsNew As FileStream = New FileStream(strFilename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
        Do
            Dim intToCopy As Integer = Math.Min(4096, bytesToWrite.Length - position)
            Dim buffer(intToCopy - 1) As Byte
            Array.Copy(bytesToWrite, position, buffer, 0, intToCopy)
            fsNew.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

            position += intToCopy

            Application.DoEvents()

        Loop While position < bytesToWrite.Length

    End Using

End Sub
```

My problem is that with large files, the byte array cannot be declared that large. I am needing to load it into a byte array to do some encryption work on the byte array. I am playing around with this code:

```
    Public Function ReadBinaryFileTest(strFilename As String) As Byte()()
    Const SIZE As Integer = &H1000 '4096 <-experiment with this value
    Dim bytes()() As Byte

    Using fsOpen As FileStream = New FileStream(strFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, SIZE)
        Dim ubound = (fsOpen.Length / SIZE) - 1
        bytes = new byte(ubound)()
        Dim read As Integer = 0

        For index As Integer = 0 To ubound
            bytes(index) = New Byte(SIZE - 1)
            read = fsOpen.Read(bytes(index), 0, SIZE)
            If read <> SIZE Then
                Array.Resize(bytes(index), read) 'this should only happen once if at all
            End If
        Next
    End Using

    Return bytes

End Function
```

However I am getting these errors:

> bytes = new byte(ubound)()

'{' expected

and

> bytes(index) = New Byte(SIZE - 1)

Type 'Byte' has no constructors.

Is this the correct way to go about this problem? If not, how should I attack it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ReDim,

```
ReDim bytes(ubound-1)
```

Or

```
 bytes = New Byte(ubound)() {}
```

Comment: How about: bytes(index) = New Byte(SIZE - 1)

Comment: Put {} -  bytes(index) = New Byte(SIZE - 1) {}